# error: no type arguments expected for class Arrayについて

Tags: kotlin

あるQiitaの記事を参考にKotlinの勉強を進めていたのですが、

```
val list: Array<Int?> = arrayOfNulls(3)
```

というコードでタイトルのようなエラーを吐いてしまいました。

いろいろ試した結果、型推論に任せて`arrayOfNulls`関数に型引数を与えるとエラーは出なくなりました。

```
val list = arrayOfNulls<Int>(3) // エラーなし
```

リファレンスを見ても、この変数`list`の型は`Array<Int?>`になると思うのですが、型を明示するとエラーになってしまいます。

```
val list: Array<Int?> = arrayOfNulls<Int>(3)
=> error: no type arguments expected for class Array
```

どうしてこのようなエラーになるのでしょうか？

Comment: https://try.kotlinlang.org/ 上のmainにその1行のコードを書いて実行してもエラーになりますか？(私はなりませんでした) Kotlinのバージョンや実行環境・方法、そのエラーが出る[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)があれば何か分かるかもしれません。

Comment: ちなみに上記サイトで問題の1行だけを書いてもconsoleに何も表示されずに成功するので、私は2行目に `list.forEach{ println(it) }`を書いてnullが3行表示されることを確認しました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。実際のスクリプトはほかの処理もあったので、エラーを吐いた部分だけ書くとなぜか実行できました。元のスクリプトでもエラーは出ませんでした。原因はよくわかりませんが、上手く動きました

Comment: もしかしたら、ファイル名が「array.kts」だったのが問題かもしれません！自動的にarrayクラスが生成され、そのためにArrayクラス(名前の先頭が大文字ですが)は引数をとらない、と言われてしまったのかもしれません

Comment: かなり有用な情報のように感じますので、よろしければご自身で回答を投稿してみてください(自身の質問に回答することは状況によりむしろ推奨されています)

Comment: わかりました、いくつか検証を重ねてみてからそうしようと思います。harry0000さんのコメントで新たな知見がありました、ありがとうございます。